# Increment part of a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, increment

I have a method in a Ruby script that is attempting to rename files before they are saved. It looks like this:

```
def increment (path)
    if path[-3,2] == "_#"
        print "    Incremented file with that name already exists, renaming\n"
        count = path[-1].chr.to_i + 1
        return path.chop! << count.to_s
    else
        print "    A file with that name already exists, renaming\n"
        return path << "_#1"
    end
end
```

Say you have 3 files with the same name being saved to a directory, we'll say the file is called `example.mp3`. The idea is that the first will be saved as `example.mp3` (since it won't be caught by `if File.exists?("#{file_path}.mp3")` elsewhere in the script), the second will be saved as `example_#1.mp3` (since it is caught by the `else` part of the above method) and the third as `example_#2.mp3` (since it is caught by the `if` part of the above method).

The problem I have is twofold.

1) `if path[-3,2] == "_#"` won't work for files with an integer of more than one digit (`example_#11.mp3` for example) since the character placement will be wrong (you'd need it to be `path[-4,2]` but then that doesn't cope with 3 digit numbers etc).

2) I'm never reaching problem 1) since the method doesn't reliably catch file names. At the moment it will rename the first to `example_#1.mp3` but the second gets renamed to the same thing (causing it to overwrite the previously saved file).

This is possibly too vague for Stack Overflow but I can't find anything that addresses the issue of incrementing a certain part of a string.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit/update:**

Wayne's method below seems to work on it's own but not when included as part of the whole script - it can increment a file once (from `example.mp3` to `example_#1.mp3`) but doesn't cope with taking `example_#1.mp3` and incrementing it to `example_#2.mp3`. To provide a little more context - currently when the script finds a file to save it is passing the name to Wayne's method like this:

```
file_name = increment(image_name)
File.open("images/#{file_name}.jpeg", 'w') do |output|
    open(image_url) do |input|
        output << input.read
    end
end
```

I've edited Wayne's script a little so now it looks like this:

```
def increment (name)
    name = name.gsub(/\s{2,}|(http:\/\/)|(www.)/i, '')
    if File.exists?("images/#{name}.jpeg")
        _, filename, count, extension = *name.match(/(\A.*?)(?:_#(\d+))?(\.[^.]*)?\Z/)
        count = (count || '0').to_i + 1
        "#{name}_##{count}#{extension}"
    else
        return name
    end
end
```

Where am I going wrong? Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to know the contents of file_name to know for sure what's gone wrong, but both my function and @Phrog's include the extension (e.g. '.jpeg') in the incremented filename.  Try changing `"images/#{file_name}.jpeg"` to `"images/#{file_name}"`.  If file_name includes a path as well, you can also remove `images/` leaving you with `File.open(filename, ...)`

Comment: `file_name` doesn't include a path or an extension. I think I've identified the problem though: when increment runs `if File.exists?("images/#{name}.jpeg")` it only checks for a non-incremented file (eg `example.jpeg`). When more than 2 files with the same `file_name` crop up all past the 2nd get written to `example_#1.jpeg`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think filename needs to include the path and extension from the very beginning.  That ought to fix it.  Except for the variable name, which should probably be `path` instead of `filename` so that the code is telling the truth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regular expression will git 'er done:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

def increment(path)
  _, filename, count, extension = *path.match(/(\A.*?)(?:_#(\d+))?(\.[^.]*)?\Z/)
  count = (count || '0').to_i + 1
  "#{filename}_##{count}#{extension}"
end

p increment('example')        # => "example_#1"
p increment('example.')       # => "example_#1."
p increment('example.mp3')    # => "example_#1.mp3"
p increment('example_#1.mp3') # => "example_#2.mp3"
p increment('example_#2.mp3') # => "example_#3.mp3"
```

This probably doesn't matter for the code you're writing, but if you ever may have multiple threads or processes using this algorithm on the same files, there's a race condition when checking for existence before saving: Two writers can both find the same filename unused and write to it.  If that matters to you, then open the file in a mode that fails if it exists, rescuing the exception.  When the exception occurs, pick a different name.  Roughly:

```
loop do
  begin
    File.open(filename, File::CREAT | File::EXCL | File::WRONLY) do |file|
      file.puts "Your content goes here"
    end
    break
  rescue Errno::EEXIST
    filename = increment(filename)
    redo
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work when run on it's own, but not when included as part of the whole script. I've expanded my original post above to explain. Also, above and beyond with the threading example :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation that doesn't accept a file name with an existing count:

```
def non_colliding_filename( filename )
  if File.exists?(filename)
    base,ext = /\A(.+?)(\.[^.]+)?\Z/.match( filename ).to_a[1..-1]
    i = 1
    i += 1 while File.exists?( filename="#{base}_##{i}#{ext}" )
  end
  filename
end
```

Proof:

```
%w[ foo bar.mp3 jim.bob.mp3 ].each do |desired|
  3.times{
    file = non_colliding_filename( desired )
    p file
    File.open( file, 'w' ){ |f| f << "tmp" }
  }
end
#=> "foo"
#=> "foo_#1"
#=> "foo_#2"
#=> "bar.mp3"
#=> "bar_#1.mp3"
#=> "bar_#2.mp3"
#=> "jim.bob.mp3"
#=> "jim.bob_#1.mp3"
#=> "jim.bob_#2.mp3"
```